# Customizing "Team Planner" views

Tags: ms-project

Is it possible to change what is displayed within the Team Planner?

I use indented Tasks to separate different aspects of projects, assigning different Resources as appropriate.  For Example, I might have

- [Indent 1] Contract Number, "#23-001"
- [Indent 2] Aspect, "Aspect 1"
- [Indent 3] Specific Task, "Do Fieldwork" (assigned to a Resource)

When they show up in the Team Planner, I have a disconnect as several Resources can show the same Task (and I lose sight of which parent Task they are attached to).  The "easy" solution would be to rename the task with all the Parent Information (using the above, "#23-001:Aspect 1: Do Fieldwork" but that gets cumbersome and repetitive when I'm in the Task View.

Ideally, I'd like to programmatically define a Text field that is created based on the OutlineParents, and then use that to drive the displayed name in the Team Planner.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Gordon,
The basic answer is "no". Project does not provide the option to display custom fields in the Team Planner view. I suggest you encode the task Name field to provide the insight you want.